# Rock, paper, scissors game javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently stuck with a rock, paper, scissors game in javascript. Only my last function game() which needs to play a round 5 times is not working. Have tried to work with a for loop but it seems that I'm getting 5 times the same answer instead of 5 different random ones.

Could someone please help me out?

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

const playerSelection = playerPlay();
const computerSelection = computerPlay();

// computer select function
function computerPlay() {

    const option = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    
    return option[random];
}

console.log('Computer: ' + computerSelection);

// player select function
function playerPlay() {

    const input = prompt('Please enter input');

    const option = input.toLowerCase();
    
    return option;
}

console.log('Player: ' + playerSelection);


// play 1 single round
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

    if(playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return 'It is a tie';
    }


    if(playerSelection === 'rock') {

        if(computerSelection === 'scissors') {
            playerScore++;
            return 'Player wins with rock';
        } else if(computerSelection === 'paper') {
            computerScore++;
            return 'Computer wins with paper'
        }
    }

    if(playerSelection === 'paper') {

        if(computerSelection === 'rock') {
            playerScore++;
            return 'Player wins with paper';
        } else if(computerSelection === 'scissors') {
            computerScore++;
            return 'Computer wins with scissors';
        }
    }

    if(playerSelection === 'scissors') {

        if(computerSelection === "paper") {
            playerScore++;
            return 'Player wins with scissors';
        } else if(computerSelection === 'rock') {
            computerScore++;
            return 'Computer wins with rock';
        }
    }

}

// console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);

console.log('Player: ' + playerScore);
console.log('Computer: ' + computerScore);


// game

function game() {

    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

       console.log('repeat 5 times');
       playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    }

}

game();
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you be more specific on what the problem is?

Comment: You only assign to `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` exactly once. No, it won't change. You have to put that part into the loop.

Comment: stop. And take some time to learn about your browser's developer tools and how to trace execution. Otherwise all you are doing is compounding frustration every line of code you write. There is a YouTube video series on "Chrome developer tool tips"  which is excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put a loop without asking for the player and computer input, hence it runs 5 times without taking any input. I have fixed this in the snippet. Not entirely sure if you want to run it this way though.

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

// computer select function
function computerPlay() {

  const option = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  return option[random];
}


// player select function
function playerPlay() {

  const input = prompt('Please enter input');

  const option = input.toLowerCase();

  return option;
}




// play 1 single round
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    return 'It is a tie';
  }


  if (playerSelection === 'rock') {

    if (computerSelection === 'scissors') {
      playerScore++;
      return 'Player wins with rock';
    } else if (computerSelection === 'paper') {
      computerScore++;
      return 'Computer wins with paper'
    }
  }

  if (playerSelection === 'paper') {

    if (computerSelection === 'rock') {
      playerScore++;
      return 'Player wins with paper';
    } else if (computerSelection === 'scissors') {
      computerScore++;
      return 'Computer wins with scissors';
    }
  }

  if (playerSelection === 'scissors') {

    if (computerSelection === "paper") {
      playerScore++;
      return 'Player wins with scissors';
    } else if (computerSelection === 'rock') {
      computerScore++;
      return 'Computer wins with rock';
    }
  }

}

// console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));


// game

function game() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var playerSelection = playerPlay();
    var computerSelection = computerPlay();
    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    console.log('Computer: ' + computerSelection);
    console.log('Player: ' + playerSelection);
    console.log('Player: ' + playerScore);
    console.log('Computer: ' + computerScore);
  }
  console.log('Final Player: ' + playerScore);
  console.log('Final Computer: ' + computerScore);

}

game();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your probleme is because you're set your `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` once (and even on a const ! So choice cannot be updated)

You just have to move this part into you `for` loop (and update to `let` instead of `const`)

```js
    let playerSelection = playerPlay();
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();
```

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

// computer select function
function computerPlay() {

    const option = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    
    return option[random];
}
// player select function
function playerPlay() {

    const input = prompt('Please enter input');

    const option = input.toLowerCase();
    
    return option;
}


// play 1 single round
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
 
    

    if(playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return 'It is a tie';
    }


    if(playerSelection === 'rock') {

        if(computerSelection === 'scissors') {
            playerScore++;
            return 'Player wins with rock';
        } else if(computerSelection === 'paper') {
            computerScore++;
            return 'Computer wins with paper'
        }
    }

    if(playerSelection === 'paper') {

        if(computerSelection === 'rock') {
            playerScore++;
            return 'Player wins with paper';
        } else if(computerSelection === 'scissors') {
            computerScore++;
            return 'Computer wins with scissors';
        }
    }

    if(playerSelection === 'scissors') {

        if(computerSelection === "paper") {
            playerScore++;
            return 'Player wins with scissors';
        } else if(computerSelection === 'rock') {
            computerScore++;
            return 'Computer wins with rock';
        }
    }

}


// game

function game() {

    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

       let playerSelection = playerPlay();
       let computerSelection = computerPlay();
       
       
       
       console.log(`[Play turn ${i}] Player: ${playerSelection} | Computer: ${computerSelection}`);
       playRound(i);
    }

}

game();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues.

1. You don't display output of next games. They are played but result is the same. It's same game configuration repeated 5 times.

   console.log('repeat 5 times');
   console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

Instead of:

```
console.log('repeat 5 times');
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

1. You run functions `playerSelection`, `computerSelection` only once. So every next play has the same result.

You should execute these functions with every loop iteration.

Example:

```
let playerSelection = function () {

    const input = prompt('Please enter input');

    const option = input.toLowerCase();

    return option;
};

let computerSelection = function () {

    const option = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    return option[random];
};

[...]

playRound(playerSelection(), computerSelection());
```